# Cross-referencing inference rules

Tags: cross-referencing, logic

I'm using the `mathpartir` package by Didier Remy for typesetting inference rules. I like the visual style of the rules, but the package doesn't integrate with the standard `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing mechanism. For example, after I typeset the modus ponens rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\begin{document}
\begin{mathpar}
  \inferrule[ABC]{
    A \\
    A \Longrightarrow B
  }{
    B
  }{{\Longrightarrow}E}
\end{mathpar}
\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to reference it later using `\ref`, and get `${\Longrightarrow}E$` rendered. Questions:

1. Can I make this work with `mathpartir`, and how? Also, a general pointer to how `\label` and `\ref` work under the hood might be useful - as I don't have all too many rules, I'd also be happy with a hacky solution.
2. Do you know any alternative packages capable of this?

Comment: Welcome! Generally, `\label` writes the value of a counter to the `.aux` file and `\ref` uses the value of that counter to create a cross-reference. Since your rules aren't numbered, I'm not entirely sure how you think this might work. There are packages which allow you to pull in the name of something instead e.g. of a section, so I guess you'd need something like that. But the standard cross-referencing system does numbers and just numbers as far as I know. (They may get formatted as letters, say e.g. A, B, C rather than 1, 2, 3 but they are still values of a counter.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default cross-referencing system relies on cross-referenced items being numbered. `\label{}` writes the value of the currently applicable counter to the `.auz` file, along with the tag given as its argument. `\ref{}` uses that tag to retrieve the value of the counter. The counter may be formatted as something other than a number e.g. `A`, `B`, `C` rather than `1`, `2`, `3`, but it is still a number underneath.

Since the inference rules aren't numbered, this obviously does not apply. Moreover, even if they were numbered, `\ref{}` would return the value of a counter and not something like `-> E`.

However, the package `nameref`, which is part of the **hyperref** package, extends the standard cross-referencing system so that the names of items such as sections can be retrieved from the `.aux` file using `\nameref{}`. It does this by redefining `\label{}` to write additional information to the `.aux` file.

We can use this framework to redefine `\inferrule` so that a subsequent `\label{}` will write the required information to the `.aux` file. By default the `-> E` is not an argument passed to `\inferrule` at all - it just comes next. So we will need to redefine `\inferrule` to accept an additional argument, preferably an optional one. We then need to set `\@currentlabelname` to the value of this argument, if present, so that `\label{}` knows what to write to the `.aux` file.

I've used `xparse` to handle the redefinition.

We start by saving the current definition of `\inferrule`. We don't need this, but the user might.

```
\let\originferrule\inferrule
```

Now we overwrite the definition to accept a final, optional argument. So the new syntax will be `\inferrule*[]{}{}[]` rather than `\inferrule*[]{}{}`.

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \inferrule { s O {} m m o }{%
```

Do we want the starred form or not?

```
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
  {%
```

All we do is pass arguments 2,3 and 4 to the relevant internal macro - either starred ...

```
    \mpr@inferstar[#2]{#3}{#4}%
  }{%
```

or not ...

```
    \mpr@inferrule[#2]{#3}{#4}%
  }%
```

Now we test if the user used an optional argument or not. If not, there's nothing to do.

```
  \IfValueT{#5}%
  {%
```

Otherwise, we add a little space,

```
    \quad
```

typeset the argument

```
    #5%
```

and pass the argument to another macro (which we define in a minute).

```
    \my@name@inferrule{#5}%
  }%
```

And that's it.

```
}
```

Now for the final macro. This just sets `\@currentlabelname` to the relevant value, wrapping it in an `\ensuremath{}` to avoid errors if the name contains symbols etc.

```
\NewDocumentCommand \my@name@inferrule { m }{%
  \def\@currentlabelname{\ensuremath{#1}}%
}
```

Then we can write

```
\begin{mathpar}
  \inferrule[Modus Ponens]{
    A \\
    A \Longrightarrow B
  }{
    B
  }[\Longrightarrow E]\label{infrule:mp}
\end{mathpar}
Applying \nameref{infrule:mp}, we see that \dots
```

to produce

[image: refer to inference rule by name]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir,xparse}
\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
\let\originferrule\inferrule
\DeclareDocumentCommand \inferrule { s O {} m m o }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
  {%
    \mpr@inferstar[#2]{#3}{#4}%
  }{%
    \mpr@inferrule[#2]{#3}{#4}%
  }%
  \IfValueT{#5}%
  {%
    \quad
    #5%
    \my@name@inferrule{#5}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \my@name@inferrule { m }{%
  \def\@currentlabelname{\ensuremath{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{mathpar}
  \inferrule[Modus Ponens]{
    A \\
    A \Longrightarrow B
  }{
    B
  }[\Longrightarrow E]\label{infrule:mp}
\end{mathpar}
Applying \nameref{infrule:mp}, we see that \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just... wow! Thank you for that detailed explanation!

Comment: Impressive and very detailed explanation, thanks!

Comment: When I use this with the starred version of inferrule (simply replacing `\inferrule` with `\inferrule*` in your MWE), I get an error (`Use of \mpr@inferstar doesn't match its definition.`). Any idea how to solve this?